# How to pass from one Containerview to Another UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uicontainerview

I'm in trouble with passing from one containerview to another UIViewController

This image below demonstrates a storyboard for what i want to do.

[image]

My app has one Containerview and I added button in this app. When I hit the button I want to pass another view via segue. But when I hit to button view is being opened on full screen. I just want to open this view, same size of containerview. Which segue can be useful for this trip? How canit be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the viewcontroller that is embedded to a UINavigationController and then make the original embedded viewcontroller the rootviewcontroller of the navigation, then you should get the desired behavior.

[image]

Comment: thanks for comment @Joseph, but i think we don't understand each :) other. Basicly i want to this stuff; when i hit button , ı want to switch containerview to view to same size of container view. NavigationController is only for switching between two views. Am i right ?

Comment: In your diagram, you show a containerview with an embedded viewcontroller and you want to segue to another viewcontroller.  Unless the segue you are wanting to do is a modal one, the way to do this is with a UINavigationController.  It is precisely what they are designed to do.

Comment: Keep in mind, that there are no limits to the number of UINavigationControllers that you can have in an application, so this solution does not preclude you have having the "first" viewController be controlled by a different UINavigationController

Comment: Thank you. You save my time. I'm looking for this concept since 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

set fixed size in attribute Inspector what you want then it will show only that size view